# WebMethod Call Within a WebMethod Call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to call a WebMethod that returns an integer, this integer is then displayed to the user in a confirm message. If they confirm then I need to call a second WebMethod and then alert them of the result via an alert message.

When I do this, everything works fine except for the second success function. That function is never reached, and the user is never alerted as a result.

This is example JavaScript of my situation:

```
$( "a" ).live( "click", function() {
    PageMethod.GetCount(OnSucceed, OnFail);
});

OnSucceed(result)
{
    var retVal = Confirm(result);

    if(retVal == false)
        return false;

    PageMethod.Create(Succ, OnFail); //Produces the correct files
}

function Succ(resultStr)
{
    alert(resultStr); //This is never reached
}

function OnFail(error)
{
    alert(error);
}
```

Comment: what is pagemethod ?

Answer (score 0):

Well .. It can be for different reasons

- You have an error calling the second PageMethod. You can check your console to see if  you have "500 INTERNALL ERROR".

  - The problem is before calling the page method but guessing you have already checked your PageMethod this is not likely.
  - You are calling PAGEMETHODS from your JS codes, but you mentioned WebMethods which are 2 different things. Make sure what is that are
    you really calling.
  - your PageMethod/WebMethod does not return anything